# Mysql syntax for alter existing column to default

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, alter-table

i have tried following queries to alter existing column with default getdate constraint

```
ALTER TABLE PartyTypes ALTER COLUMN CreatedDate GetDate();
ALTER TABLE partytypes ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Constraint DEFAULT GetDate() FOR CreatedDate;
```

both are giving error

> ALTER TABLE partytypes ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Constraint DEFAULT GetDate() FOR CreatedDate Error Code: 1064. You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT GetDate() FOR
>   CreatedDate' at line 1    0.000 sec

any updates on this

Comment: Using `workbench` right click on the table and select `Alter Table`. Then using the GUI its more easy to set the default for the desired column

Comment: nope...i want to do this from query....as it will be helpfull for others also...and what is wrong with sql query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify any foreign table.

Constraints are **only** foreign keys, not limitations to column values. What you might want to use is a trigger or set the default to now():

```
ALTER TABLE PartyTypes CHANGE COLUMN CreatedDate CreatedDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW();
```

Be sure to provide the column name twice, so you don't rename it.

More on the syntax of `ALTER TABLE` can be found in the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html).

Comment: What is `GetDate()`? Does not exist in MySQL

Comment: Are we talking about SQL Server or MySQL? Your tag says MySQL. And MySQL does not have any function called `GetDate`

Comment: we are talking about executing this in mysql..sorry to mix with sql server..but i just wanted to know what works in mysql in place of getdate()

Comment: If you are interested in only the date, call `date(now())` instead of `now()`

Comment: Then try `curdate()`

Comment: so then only `now()` is working. Why not keep `now()`?